# Do Custom Fonts on Android decrease performance?

Tags: android, performance, mobile, custom-font

I'm planning to make an android app and want to use custom fonts to match the style guide provided by the brand who wants the app.

I have found this library [Caligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) to use custom fonts.

1. Is there an issue regarding performance of the app by using custom
   fonts with this library?
2. Is there another option to add custom fonts painlessly?
3. Also, is there a guideline that prevents from using custom fonts in android apps, or is it a bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is there an issue regarding performance of the app by using custom fonts with this library?

There generally isn't any issue with custom fonts, there is no reason this library would hit the performance of the app

> 2. Is there another option to add custom fonts painlessly?

Yes you can easily achieve this with simple coding

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "your_font.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

> 3. Also, is there a guideline that prevents from using custom fonts in android apps, or is it a bad practice?

No it is not a bad practice. Infact google recently added an option to use custom fonts with support library v26. You wont have to add ttf file to the apk, google will download that for you itself

Comment: The code you mentioned in point 2 should be done for every TextView? Is there a global setting for that purpose instead of assigning each TextView?

Comment: Yes it has to be done for every textview. I usually subclass textview and add fonts via xml to it. Let me know if you want the code for it